# custom defined charts based on query result in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to plot values based on a output of a specific query result in Mongodb periodically (say every minute) and display in a chart-like form? There're plugins and tools available that would display the standard metrics in order to monitor the Mongo instances like in the new relic, nagios, munin or MMS. But they all display the built in charts and I want to take this a little further where the chart would display the values based on my custom query result on a particular database and a particular collection. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So I could achieve this with the help of nagios. First by creating a shell script that would output the result of the custom query (which is some number) by using the --eval in the shell to execute a mongo query. Then I created a NRPE command. NRPE is a nagios way to have commands run by the clients (hosts) instead of the server so I had to add my new command in /etc/nagios/nrpe.conf . So define the command there, for example

## CCU check (for mongodb)

command[check_gluon_ccu_player_db]=/path/to/scripts/ccu.sh

Next on nagios server add the new command in commands.cgs 
example:

## CCU

define command{
        command_name    check_gluon_ccu_player_db
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_gluon_ccu_player_db
} 
and also in nagios add the service definition for that server (servers/myhost-1)

## CCU

define service{
        use                             crit-linux-service
        host_name                       myhost-1
        service_description             Player CCU
        check_command                   check_gluon_ccu_player_db
}

That's it. After some time the data should start flowing thru the nagios chart.